# Microsoft Exchange library for iOS

Tags: ios, office365, exchangewebservices

We've been searching high and low for a library to connect to Microsoft Exchange and Office365 to manage/view calendar events in an iOS application - without any luck. We need to support on-prem Exchange servers so using Graph is not an option. Is our only option to write our own SOAP integration against the managed API or does someone know of a library (free or payed) we can use?

Best regards,
Christopher

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the "Office 365 SDKs for iOS" [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-iOS). It easily integrate services and data from Office 365 into native iOS apps using these Objective-C libraries.

Comment: That library does not support Exchange usage.

Comment: Office 365 (Exchange Online) and a OnPremises Exchange are mostly two different products. So I´m very sure that you will not find a library which will support both.